# How to hide RadAjaxLoadingPanel when Ajaxifying

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a RadAjaxLoadingPanel in my master page. My page (uses the same master page) has **Date Criteria** RadComboBox whose selectedindexchanged event will set **Start Date** and **End Date** (RadDatePicker controls).

The functionality is to prepopulate the Start and End Date on selection of the Date Criteria. I am ajaxifying the Date Criteria and setting the TargetControls as Start Date and End Date. The RadAjaxLoadingPanel is visible for both controls when any ajaxified control posts back by default.

[image]

My requirement is to hide displaying the RadAjaxLoadingPanel on those two date pickers when this RadComboBox index changes. How do I do it?

I tried OnRequestStart & OnResponseEnd. It didn't take any effect.

Please suggest.

Regards,
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DefaultLoadingPanelID set for your RadAjaxManager - remove it. Then, make sure the AjaxSetting that corresponds to the control you do not want to show a loading panel does not have the LoadingPanelID property set on the UpdatedControls.